# Variable number of lines underneath the question

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

I was trying to create a booklet for an assessment. I have been required to put use a list (normal enumnerate environment) for the questions, but to write down, after each question lines up to the end of the page and then another entire page of lines. The lines should not he indented after the question. Obviously, each question can have different height, so the number of lines after the question might change. I have tried in a very naive way but I was curious if this could be automatised.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn,oneside]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{height=245mm,width=160mm}
\parindent=0pt

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \lipsum[1]

\vspace{1cm}\hrule
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,30}
    {\vspace{0.7cm}\hrule}

\item \lipsum[2]
\vspace{1cm}\hrule
\foreach \n in {1,2,...,20}
    {\vspace{0.7cm}\hrule}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The problem with my solution is that every time I change a tiny bit of the question, I need to work out again the number of lines in each page, wasting a lot of time. I hope there is a much better solution, that automatically puts lines up to the end.

Thank you!

Comment: Ti*k*Z allows you to measure the remaining space on the page and thus to compute the number of lines that needs to be inserted. Presumably something like \pagegoal will work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use leaders:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\makelines}{%
  \par
  \xleaders\vbox{\vskip2\baselineskip\hrule width\textwidth}\vfill
  \newpage
  \hrule width 0pt
  \xleaders\vbox{\vskip2\baselineskip\hrule width\textwidth}\vfill
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item \lipsum[1]\makelines

\item \lipsum[2]\makelines

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the picture shows lines with different thickness, but it's only an effect of rasterization.

Comment: This is an amazing solution. Easy, elegant and clear. Thank you so much @egreg.

Comment: @Logos Vertical leaders are a very nice item in my toolbox. `;-)`